# Drawing high resolution image to canvas delays all elements from being shown - how fix this?

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm drawing 6 images with a resolution of 300dpi to 6 different canvases when a containing `DIV` is shown. When this occurs, it causes all the other `DIV`s  within the parent to not show until the drawing is done.

Even if I delay the drawing with `setTimeout( draw(), 200 )`, the problem still occurs. It only fixes it if I delay the drawing for a long time (e.g. 1000ms). But that's too long of a delay.

The problem only seems to show up on Google Chrome.

How can I get it to show all `DIV`s while drawing the canvases?

**EDIT: I realized that it was custom fonts which do not show up and are stopped from loading until the images load and the canvases are drawn. Using built-in fonts, causes those elements to show immediately**

Comment: Do you have example code? Are you drawing using the image.onload or a preloader?

Comment: @ShalomAptekar Using image.onload. But the loading of the image is not what delays it. I changed the code to still load all the images but not draw them to the canvases and it still delayed all other elements. I also tried drawing all the images to one canvas (I kept track of all images loaded and on the last one, drew them all to one large canvas) and it still had the delay.

Comment: hummm... and you are running all javascript after the dom loads? or is it an ajaxed solution?

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out :-)